# Sed replace string with multi-lines

Tags: regex, sed, editor, text-editor

I have simple sed command:

```
#!/bin/bash
COMMAND=$1
sed -e "s#COMMAND#$COMMAND#
```

The value for command should be a new line for every command but i cannot figure out how to give them to sed and sed put every command on new line. What i have tried is:

```
 ./script 'ls\n date\n uname\n'
```

Regards!

Comment: i`m trying to insert new lines in $1 and sed to catch that new lines.

Comment: I don't quite get it. You want to put a string of space-separated commands as argument of your script and output them each on  new line? Or pipe them through `sed` line-wise to do what? Could you give us the input and expected output, please?

Comment: Your script sort-of works for me. But your sed command is not complete. There is a quote missing and you have no input.

Comment: edit your Q to how the required output from your sed cmd. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question, you are looking to replace a representation of newlines within a string (i.e. a backslash character, followed by an 'n') as actual printed newlines.

The following script takes a single quoted string (the input as shown in your question) containing the literals '\n' and converts those into actual new lines.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n $1 | sed -e 's#\\n#\n#g'
```

Example usage:

```
[user@localhost ~]$ ./simple_sed.sh 'ls\ndate\nuname\n' 
ls
date
uname
```

The changes needed from your script are to

- 1. echo the argument, otherwise sed expects a file and will do nothing;
- 2. match the \\n and replace it with a newline; and
- 3. add a 'g' to the end which will continue searching within a line after a replacement has occurred (read: multiple \n are substituted in a single line).